# Is there danger in accessing a third partition from my virtualbox guest installed on a partition

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, virtualbox, partitioning, multi-boot

I recently configured my laptop to dual boot windows 10 and ubuntu 16.04.

The set up is that I have 6 partitions on a single 1TB drive, of those only 3 are set up as usable drives (rest are recovery, swap, efi). On one I have the win10 install with apps, on one I have the ubuntu install with apps, the other is a drive I have used to share data between the two setups.

I recently followed (loosely) this approach: https://lifehacker.com/how-to-dual-boot-and-virtualize-the-same-partition-on-y-493223329

So that I can now access the ubuntu partition as a virtualised guest from windows.

If you look at the referenced guide and the linked vbox docs, there are some big old warnings about letting the host/guest access one anothers partitions so i have made sure to hide these from myself on each system.

What I'm now wondering is is it safe for me to access my shared data drive simultaneously from both systems (note: it IS NOT shared as a virtualbox share - both oses have visibility of the physical disk). Is this situation likely to cause corruption?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## The Wrong Way

Directly accessing a partition from two different operating systems via native file system drivers is **extremely** dangerous. This is because native fs drivers are designed with the assumption that they have exclusive access to the file system. They are not aware of each others changes to the MFT/Journal of the respective file system and there may be race conditions where both try to write to the same sector at the same time. The risk of data loss, just from having the fs mounted (not actively accessing it) is very high. Actively writing to a drive mounted this way virtually guarantees filesystem corruption if not data loss.

At most you should only directly mount a physical file system in a guest OS if that fs is unmounted in the host OS (and there are still risks) or mounted on the guest OS as immutable (which still won't become aware of changes the host makes).

## The Right Way

The simplest and most reliable option is to use a Virtualbox shared folder mapped to the root of the file system you wish to share. I do this myself like so:

[image]

You can then mount the shared drive in the guest machine. You must have Virtualbox Guest Additions installed on the guest to do so. In *nix simply use the mount command with the device matching the share name and the fstype "vbox". In Windows look in Network Locations and you can `right-click` > `Map Network Drive` on the share.

Comment: thanks for the answer, very helpful, (i have turned it off for now) - Quick follow up since you seem quite knowledgeable around this area: 1: you say risk of having disk just mounted is very high, does this apply to the efi volume, does windows see that? cause it's mounted in ubuntu, also Im concerned installing virtualbox additions will cause errors when booting into the normal desktop (have read so), do you know if they could be loaded conditionally?

Comment: the EFI partition is actually a FAT32 partition but it's type flag is set to EFI. Windows does see it, but afaik it should refuse to mount it for *user* access. However, Windows does read and write to that partition when updating it's bootloader. This is something that may happen in an automated manner such as through windows updates. That's the risk with even mounting these file systems... there are automated processes under windows and linux that may write to these drives without you knowing.

Comment: As for virtualbox guest additions, they are wroking without problems on both my Ubuntu and Mint (an Ubuntu based distro) guests without issue. I'm certain it's possible to have errors durring start up, but it isn't (afaik) the norm. I'm not sure how you would set up conditional X.org config... but it shoudl be possible to add an entry in grub2 that disables the kernel modules added by the VBox Guest Additions installer. Also, it's best to use the guest additions that match your virtualbox version. Unfortunately the ones in the ubuntu repo are old. Use `Devices` > `Insert Guest Additions CD`.